# How to do pointfree style with long parameter list

Tags: scala, haskell, f#, pointfree

I've got a function that creates an Async workflow, and the function that takes 10 arguments in curry style.  e.g.

```
let createSequenceCore a b c d e f g h i j = 
  async { 
    ... 
  }
```

I want to create another function to start that workflow, so I've got

```
let startSequenceCore a b c d e f g h i j =
  Async.StartImmediate (createSequenceCore a b c d e f g h i j)
```

Is there any way I can get rid of those redundant parameters?  I tried the `<<` operator, but that only lets me remove one.

```
let startSequenceCore a b c d e f g h i =
  Async.StartImmediate << (createSequenceCore a b c d e f g h i)
```

(I added Haskell and Scala to this question even though the code itself is F#, as really what I want is just how to do this kind of currying, which would apply to any; I'd think a Haskell or Scala answer would be easily portable to F# and could well be marked as the correct answer).

**NOTE** Reasonably well showing that there is not an easy solution to this could also get the bounty.

---

**UPDATE** geesh I'm not going to give 100 points to an answer that argues with the question rather than answering it, even if it's the highest voted, so here:

I've got a function that creates an Async workflow, and the function that takes **4** arguments in curry style.  e.g.

```
let createSequenceCore a b c d = 
  async { 
    ... 
  }
```

I want to create another function to start that workflow, so I've got

```
let startSequenceCore a b c d =
  Async.StartImmediate (createSequenceCore a b c d)
```

Is there any way I can get rid of those redundant parameters?  I tried the `<<` operator, but that only lets me remove one.

```
let startSequenceCore a b c =
  Async.StartImmediate << (createSequenceCore a b c)
```

Comment: Added more complete answer as an edit, please check it out.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

10 arguments sounds like too many... How about you'd create a record with 10 properties instead, or maybe a DU where you don't need all 10 in every case? Either way, you'd end up with a single argument that way and normal function composition works as expected again.

**EDIT:** When you actually need it, you can create a more powerful version of the `<<` and `>>` operators thusly:

```
let (<.<) f = (<<) (<<) (<<) f
let (<..<) f = (<<) (<<) (<.<) f
let (<...<) f = (<<) (<<) (<..<) f

let flip f a b = f b a
let (>.>) f = flip (<.<) f
let (>..>) f = flip (<..<) f
let (>...>) f = flip (<...<) f
```

and then you can just write:

```
let startSequenceCore =
    Async.StartImmediate <...< createSequenceCore
```

or

```
let startSequenceCore =
    createSequenceCore >...> Async.StartImmediate
```

P.S.: The argument `f` is there, so that the type inference infers generic args as opposed to `obj`.

Answer (score 6):

As already mentioned by @Daniel Fabian, 10 arguments is way too many. In my experience even 5 arguments is too many and the code becomes unreadable and error prone. Having such functions usually signals a bad design. See also [Are there guidelines on how many parameters a function should accept?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/145055/61231)

However, if you insist, it's possible to make it point-free, although I doubt it gains any benefit. I'll give an example in Haskell, but I believe it'd be easy to port to F# as well. The trick is to nest the function composition operator:

```hs
data Test = Test
  deriving (Show)

createSequenceCore :: Int -> Int -> Int -> Int -> Int
                   -> Int -> Int -> Int -> Int -> Int -> Test
createSequenceCore a b c d e f g h i j = Test

-- the original version
startSequenceCore :: Int -> Int -> Int -> Int -> Int
                  -> Int -> Int -> Int -> Int -> Int -> IO ()
startSequenceCore a b c d e f g h i j =
  print (createSequenceCore a b c d e f g h i j)

-- and point-free:
startSequenceCore' :: Int -> Int -> Int -> Int -> Int
                   -> Int -> Int -> Int -> Int -> Int -> IO ()
startSequenceCore' =
  (((((((((print .) .) .) .) .) .) .) .) .) . createSequenceCore
```

Replacing `f` with `(f .)` lifts a function to work one argument inside, as we can see by adding parentheses to the type of `(.)`:

```hs
(.) :: (b -> c) -> ((a -> b) -> (a -> c))
```

See also this illuminating blog post by Conal Elliott: [Semantic editor combinators](http://conal.net/blog/posts/semantic-editor-combinators)

Comment: I'm tempted to say 10 of _anything_ is too much, if it happens without a meaningful abstraction layer. Much like [if you encounter a number higher than 8.7, you're not doing real maths](http://xkcd.com/899/).

Comment: @leftaroundabout Nice!

Answer (score 2):

You could tuple the arguments to `createSequenceCore`:

```
let createSequenceCore(a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i, j) = 
  async { 
    ... 
  }

let startSequenceCore =
  createSequenceCore >> Async.StartImmediate
```

Comment: I reordered the functions in `startSequenceCore` so that it can be read left-to-right as you would do with the `|>` operator.

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming you just want to write clean code as opposed to allow currying one parameter at a time.

Just write your own composeN function.

```
let compose4 g f x0 x1 x2 x4  = 
    g (f x0 x1 x2 x4)

let startSequenceCore =
    compose4 Async.StartImmediate createSequenceCore
```